# ConTeXt bibliography - Cannot change or edit technical report label

Tags: bibtex, context

I am trying to use @techreport in my bibliography and to have the Technical report label or type changed.

I tried following MWE,

```
\startbuffer[bib]

@techreport{Doe2019,
   author = {Jane Doe},
   address = {Brussel},
   institution = {European Parliamentary Research Service},
   title = {The EU poultry meat and egg sector},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Not technical report} % I want to use othe type.
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[default][bib.buffer]
\loadbtxdefinitionfile[apa]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\definebtxrendering[default][apa][specification=apa,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]

\starttext

\startbodymatter

I want the change the label Technical report into something else \cite[Doe2019].  But it is shown twice. The one in the box bracket is not desirable.
\\
\\
\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

The resulting pdf shows the changed label twice, one in the box bracket and another in the round bracket.
[image: My poor bibliography]

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`publ-imp-apa.mkvi:1506-1512` has:

```tex
% A report published by a school or other institution, usually numbered within a series.
% Required fields: author, title, institution, year.
% Optional fields: type, number, address, month, note.

\startsetups btx:apa:list:techreport
    \fastsetup{btx:apa:list:book}
\stopsetups
```

so a technical report is equivalent to a book.

`publ-imp-apa.mkvi:1382-1385` has:

```tex
\startsetups btx:apa:list:book
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:authoryear}
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:title-if-not-placed}
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:type}
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:editionset}
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:wherefrom-publisher}
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:url-doi-note}
\stopsetups
```

Now if we look at `publ-imp-apa.mkvi:1113-1123`:

```tex
\starttexdefinition mutable protected btx:apa:editionset
    \setmode{btx:apa:editionset-is-empty}
    \doif {\currentbtxcategory} {techreport} {
        \texdefinition{btx:apa:leftparenthesis-or-comma}
        \btxdoifelse {type} {
            \btxusecommand [apa:\s!list:type] {
                \btxflush{type}
            }
        } {
            \btxlabeltext{technicalreport}
        }
```

we can see that both `btx:apa:type` and `btx:apa:editionset` typeset the type, which is the source of this problem.

I'm not sure if you want to remove the [bracketed] type or the (parenthesized) type; the following code will do either:

```tex
\startbuffer[bib]
@techreport{Doe2019,
   author = {Jane Doe},
   address = {Brussel},
   institution = {European Parliamentary Research Service},
   title = {The EU poultry meat and egg sector},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Not technical report}
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[default][bib.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

%% Remove the [bracketed] type
% \letcsname btx:apa:type\endcsname\relax
%% [end]

%% Remove the (parenthesized) type
\let\origbtxrightparenthesisperiod\btxrightparenthesisperiod
\def\resetbtxrightparenthesisperiod{%
    \let\btxrightparenthesisperiod\origbtxrightparenthesisperiod%
}
\def\btxtypehelper#-{%
    \removepunctuation%
    \let\btxrightparenthesisperiod\resetbtxrightparenthesisperiod%
}
\setupbtx[apa:list:type][command=\btxtypehelper]
%% (end)

\startTEXpage
\nocite[Doe2019]
\placelistofpublications
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

[image]